# Monument AI Imports Data Incorrectly

Tags: validation, import, forecasting, import-from-excel

Whenever I import CSV or Excel data onto Monument, there several errors that occur:

1. Monument changes the dates in the original CSV file to different set of dates
2. Monument omits data
3. Monument misinterprets data

See images below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFE0C.jpg)

How to fix these errors?

Answer (score 0):

The team is adding support more varieties of date formats, but the safest way to import dates is to use `YYYY-MM-DD` for dates or `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` for time.

The most recent release should not have an issue with your formats, though.  So maybe check that you have the latest.

Comment: My Monument version is 1.3.29 Electron: 8.2.2/12.13.0. Is that the latest version? If not, there isn't an update function on the desktop app itself. How to update it?

Comment: @DeveloperX Create an account on the site with the email address that you used to purchase your license.  You'll then have access to an account page where you can download the latest production release.

Comment: Monument starts to have a new bug. It says "The Registration failed on timeout. Please try again later or contact Monument AI." No matter how many times I try, it keeps giving the same error message. How to fix?

Comment: You should contact customerservice@monument.ai